# Method getAttribute Reportad as Null when called on document.currentScript Inside a Script Loaded from a SCRIPT Tag

Tags: javascript

Inside a script that is loaded into a document through a SCRIPT tag, I have the following function.

```
window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
    console.log ( 'jQuery Mask Plugin v1.14.16 initializing inline as part of LeadLife_InputMask_Engine initialization' );
    const _LeadLife_InputMask_Engine_SCRIPTSOURCE = document.currentScript.getAttribute ( 'src' );
    console.log ( '_LeadLife_InputMask_Engine_SCRIPTSOURCE = ' + _LeadLife_InputMask_Engine_SCRIPTSOURCE );
```

When the function executes, the statement that starts with **const** raises a **TypeError**, saying that **getAttribute** is **null**.

Similar code in several other script modules executes without issue.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You are very clearly trying to use that in an event handler. See the docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript

> It's important to note that this will not reference the  element if the code in the script is being called as a callback or event handler; it will only reference the element while it's initially being processed.